# How to build an architecture of any Programming Project?

Tags: php, architecture

I am a PHP Programmer and willing design my own architecture to work on please suggest me what do i need to design the architecture for any project in PHP? Project is a shopping cart,WIndows or Linux would be the OS  Db has to be Mysql. PHP is the scripting language to be used for development

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What kind of project? What's the scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand the requirements, both functional (the behaviour of the application) and non-functional e.g. performance, security, reliability etc.

Understand the constraints you're working within (e.g. technologies available, cost constraints, servers to run on etc.)

Understand the context - what other systems you might need to integrate with, who your users are, where they are based, what they need to do etc.

Then you need to produce a 'component' model showing what kind of functionality needs to be encapsulated together in which software components and what interfaces they present.  This allows you to map out both the static structure of the inter-relationships e.g. inheritence / class design and also the dynamic behaviour (what talks to what when - e.g. using sequence diagrams).

Then you can move to designing the deployment architecture of which software components would sit on which hardware nodes, and hence map out network connectivity etc.

Much more, but there's a starter...

Comment: I Like It.. But I dnt know I feel like something else is missing.. Not completely satisfied with reply

Comment: More information around the kind of project / environment etc. would allow a more specific answer, what I've described here is just a very general architectural approach